# Counting categorical variables within group_by()

Tags: r, group-by, categories

I am examining conservation easement data from [NCED](https://www.conservationeasement.us/). I have a data frame of parcels that have some repeated IDs and owners.  I want to group the repeated IDs into a single row with a count of the distinct number of owners... but based on [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36700028/count-number-of-occurrences-of-categorical-variables-in-data-frame-r) I'm just returning a count of the number of rows of the ID.

```
uniqueID <- c(1:10)
parcelID <- c('a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c')
owner <- c('owner1', 'owner1', 'owner1', 'owner2', 'owner3',
           'owner2', 'owner2', 'owner2', 'owner3', 'owner1')
mydat1 <- data.frame(uniqueID, parcelID, owner)

numberOwners <- mydat1 %>% group_by(parcelID, owner) %>% tally()
```

My desired output would be:

```
  parcelID_grouped nOwners
1                a       3
2                b       1
3                c       2
```

Comment: both of those work... if you submit as answer I'll green check it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using **`dplyr`** there a couple of ways to do this:

```
library(dplyr)

mydat1 %>% distinct(parcelID, owner) %>% count(parcelID) 

mydat1 %>% group_by(parcelID) %>% summarise(n = n_distinct(owner))
```

Both calls resulting in:

```
#   parcelID     n
# 1 a            3
# 2 b            1
# 3 c            2
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `data.table`:-

```
library(data.table)
setDT(mydat1)
mydat1[, uniqueID := NULL]
mydat1 <- unique(mydat1)
mydat1[, nOwners := .N, by = parcelID]
mydat1[, owner := NULL]
mydat1 <- unique(mydat1)
setnames(mydat1, "parcelID", "parcelID_grouped")
```

You'll get the desired output:-

```
     parcelID_grouped   nOwners
1:                a       3
2:                b       1
3:                c       2
```